# What is the number of contiguous subsequences in this binary word?

Tags: list-manipulation

I want to count the number of times the contiguous sublist `0,1,0` occurs in the binary word `0,1,0,1,0,0,1`.  It occurs twice.  I tried

```
Cases[{0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1}, {___, 0, 1, 0, ___}
```

Answer (score 8):

Probably the simplest way is to use [`SequenceCount`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SequenceCount):

```
SequenceCount[{0,1,0,1,0,0,1}, {0,1,0}, Overlaps->True]
```

> 2

If you have a long list and performance matters, than a version based on [`ListCorrelate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListCorrelate) might be better:

```
l=RandomInteger[1,10^6];
SequenceCount[l, {0,1,0}, Overlaps->True] //RepeatedTiming
Total @ UnitStep @ (ListCorrelate[{-1,1,-1}, l]-1)//RepeatedTiming
```

> {0.06, 124777}
>
> {0.020, 124777}

Comment: Is SequenceCount a new function?  I am using Mma 9 and it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @GeoffreyCritzer Yes, it's new in M10.1. You can always use the ListCorrelate version then.

Answer (score 1):

```
list = {0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1};
```

Using `Subsequences` (new in 10.4)

```
Count[{0, 1, 0}] @ Subsequences[list, {3}]
```

2

Using `Partition`

```
Count[{0, 1, 0}] @ Partition[list, 3, 1]
```

2

Answer (score 1):

Using `SequenceCases`:

```
Length@SequenceCases[{0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1}, s : {0, 1, 0} :> s, Overlaps -> True]

(*2*)
```